# R -- Sorting data in a matrix using ranked data in a separate matrix

Tags: r

I am attempting to order data in a matrix using ranked data from a different matrix using R.

I have two matrices (X) and (rank).  Each matrix has the same number of columns and rows.  I would like to re-order the data in the columns from matrix (X) using the ranked data from the columns in matrix (rank).  Column 1 in (X) should be ordered using the ranked data from column 1 in (rank).

I have searched the internet for a couple of days and have not come up with anything.  I would appreciate any assistance.

Example:

Matrix (X)

Col1: A,B,C,D,E

Col2: A,B,C,D,E

Matrix (rank)

Col1: 2,4,5,3,1

Col2: 3,2,4,1,5

Goal Matrix (X.rank)

Col1: B,D,E,C,A

Col2: C,B,D,A,E

Thanks again.

Comment: I think I understand but please provide us with a reproducible example of the 2 starting matices and example of the final output.  Doesn't have to be large.

Comment: It would be something similar to this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you may want something like this:

```
R> X <- matrix(c(1:10, (1:10)^2), 10, 2, byrow=FALSE)
R> rank <- seq(10,1,by=-1)    # simple decreasing rank
R> X
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    2    4
 [3,]    3    9
 [4,]    4   16
 [5,]    5   25
 [6,]    6   36
 [7,]    7   49
 [8,]    8   64
 [9,]    9   81
[10,]   10  100
R> X[rank,]
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   10  100
 [2,]    9   81
 [3,]    8   64
 [4,]    7   49
 [5,]    6   36
 [6,]    5   25
 [7,]    4   16
 [8,]    3    9
 [9,]    2    4
[10,]    1    1
R>
```

I am not sure if you want to reorder each column of the matrix independently. To me, that does not make too much sense as we commonly keep matrices with *rows per observation* and columns for the variables---so you'd want to keep the rows together.

But you may have a different need, and what I have done here for the whole matrix can be done the same way column by column with individual assignments.

Comment: I ended up making this work in a round about way.  Thank you all for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might help you with this problem

```
# vector
x = rnorm(5)

# ranks
y = sample(5)

# sort vector based on ranks
x[match(sort(y), y)]
```

You can wrap this around an `apply` call to work on the entire matrix. Note that this may not be the most efficient solution. So if your matrix is large, let people know, so that the solution might be more focused.

EDIT. Here is an extended example that wraps the call in `sapply` to achieve the same for a matrix.

```
x = matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 2)  # original matrix to sort
y = cbind(sample(5), sample(5))  # rank matrix for sort order
sapply(1:NCOL(x), function(i) {
  .x = x[,i]; .y = y[,i]
  .x[match(sort(.y), .y)]
})
```